# Post form Ajax to Controller erro 404 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a response 404 from controller on submit simple form.

javascript:

```
var FunctionName= function () {
var form = $("#formId").serialize();
form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Cliente/Register",
        data: form,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //todo
            }
            else {
                //todo
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(".LoginMessage").html("Erro");
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(FormCollection values)
    {...}
```

When I remove the action filter "[httpPost]" the system finds the method, someone help me please...

Comment: `404` is Not found error. That means he cannot find `/Cliente/Register`. make sure url is written correctly

Comment: I know what 404 is. What I do not understand is because it is occurring because the url is right.

Comment: can you add add (ActionName=Register) with [HttpPost] and try again?

Comment: Doesn't work....The request "found" the method...but while the method executing, the page 404 show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

> type: "POST",

To

> method: "POST",

"method" is the property where you set the type of your request. Since you have not specified it, it's taking its default value "GET". Thats why if you remove the action filter, the method is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misspelling your URL.

Change this:

```
url: "/Client/Register",
```

To

```
url: "/Client/Register",
```

There is an extra "e" letter at the end of the word "Client".